# Substituting fresnos for habaneros to lower the heat

Tags: chili-peppers

Anyone know of a thinner walled chili pepper that is mild like the Fresno pepper? Like the taste of the Fresno but it's a bit too meaty, and it doesn't blend (the skin) to a smooth consistency like the habanero. Straining the sauce was my first thought, but doing so changed the consistency of the sauce to much. Trying to cut down on the heat. Also needs to be red so I can keep that bright color the sauce has.

Comment: Which way are you going? What was the starting pepper and which the ending one? Your title sounds like you're trying to replace fresno peppers with habaneros.

Comment: @Catija Edited so the title matches the content. I find that many, many people do that reversal for some reason.

Comment: The starting pepper is habanero, was to hot so I cut the amount of habaneros in half and replaced with fresnos. Now looking for a thinner walled pepper to replace the Fresno.

Comment: Catija u may want to find a hobby other then bashing, correcting and deleting people's posts. This site was created to help people find answers to questions theyre having trouble finding on they're own. If you feel a question is not up to ur standards then simply pass it over. For instance this post, you correct it, then ask multiple question in a derogatory manor then never answer them. So what was the point of all ur input? Since u seem to be the self proclaimed authority of this site maybe u can figure out how to block yourself from seeing my posts, I know I would appreciate that. Thank you